# How to enable embedded jetty with https and ssl

Tags: java, ssl

Hello I have a question regarding enabling embedded jety with https and ssl. I am completely dummy regarding this issue.
I want to follow this code:

http://www.smartjava.org/content/embedded-jetty-client-certificates

but I need to have server and client keystore. I have followed this:
http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-ssl.html#generating-csr-from-openssl

to generate the keys but I have no idea how to use them and on the other hand I am not sure if that's that I want.

any idea? by the way my jetty version is 8.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Once I had some problem with ssl websites to download stuff from it.
I dont know its the same problem but I could make this trusted object. And with it I can manage the https connection and download:

```
// Create a new trust manager that trust all certificates
  TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
      new X509TrustManager() {
          public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
              return null;
          }
          public void checkClientTrusted(
              java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
          }
          public void checkServerTrusted(
              java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
          }
      }
  };

  // Activate the new trust manager
  try {
      SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
      sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
      HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
  } catch (Exception e) {
  }


  URL url = new URL(src);
  URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
  InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
  BufferedImage bufImgOne = ImageIO.read(url);
  ImageIO.write(bufImgOne, "jpg", new File("test.jpg"));
```

> if its not the solution just or almost please write than i try to help
>   or simply delete to not spam your thread

Comment: This is for client side, right? And OP wants to have SSL on the server side

Comment: yes this is client side